# Cancel/Abort Geo.searchByText() request

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

In my NextJS v14 app I have an input in which a user can search for an address, like so:

[image]

Behind the scenes there's a simple request - done inside `useEffect` - similar to:

```js
import { Geo } from "@aws-amplify/geo";

const result = await Geo.searchByText(query, {
   countries: ["ITA"],
   // Other filters/limits
});
```

My question is, is there a way to cancel/abort the request like there is for other services (e.g. [cancel storage download](https://docs.amplify.aws/nextjs/build-a-backend/storage/download/#cancel-a-download-task), [cancel api request](https://docs.amplify.aws/nextjs/build-a-backend/graphqlapi/query-data/#cancel-read-requests), etc.)?